# How to setup Kinvey on Android?

Tags: android, gradle, kinvey

I am trying to setup Kinvey for android. After I setup the gradle the library is supported. But when I try to build the Projekt I keep getting an error. "Finished with non-exit value 2"?!

```html
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:assembleDebug]
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72310Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2310Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72310Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42310Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareKinveyAndroid2105Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources
:app:preDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:dexDebug
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/kinvey/android/callback/KinveyUserCallback;
 at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
 at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
 at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
 at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
 at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
 at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:502)
 at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)
 at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
 at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
 at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)


Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

This is my gradle:

```html
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "dominik.de.diefitnessapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}



dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile(name:'kinvey-android-2.10.5', ext:'aar')

}
```

Can anybody help me on this?

Comment: Your error is actually `Multiple dex files define Lcom/kinvey/android/callback/KinveyUserCallback;`... Do a search for "Multiple dex files define" and you'll get lots of hits

Comment: There is no need to add `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])` twice. See if you have two different jar files in your libs directory.

Comment: Jup, that worked. Thank you! @cricket_007

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess the problem lies around the fact that you are compiling your libs folder twice.

Try removing one of these lines

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using v3 (v2 will be off november, 2017) you should do this in your gradle:

```
compile ':kinvey-android:+@aar'
compile ':relinker:+@aar'
compile ':realm-android-library:+@aar'
```